# How to change the value of an instance variable of an object that didn't call the method?

Tags: java, object, methods, scope

I'm writing a program in java in which I'd like to change the value of an instance variable of an object inside a method, while that object hasn't called the method. I'm trying to do something similar to the attached code. I'd like to change object2.num inside the method myMethod, but that will give an error, as object2 is outside the scope of myMethod.

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Item object1 = new Item(2);
    Item object2 = new Item(4);
    
    object1.myMethod();
    System.out.println(object1.num + " " + object2.num);
  }
}

class Item {
  
  int num;

  Item(int n) {
    num = n;
  }

  public int myMethod() {
    object2.num *= this.num;
    this.num *= object2.num;
  }
}
```

The only solution I've come up with is to give object1 an additional instance variable, num2, which will act as object2.num. Outside of the method, I will then change object2.num to object1.num2. However, this seems very suboptimal and will get annoying when working with multiple variables to change. Is there any more efficient way to achieve this?

I'm still pretty new to coding and there might already be a solution to this, so any help or a link to a solution will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about passing a parameter into `myMethod` such as `public void myMethod(Item otherItem) {...}`?

Comment: Is all that code you posted in _one_ file? If it is, that could be confusing you. If you have a file `Item.java` for the "Item" class it would contain, from the code you posted, the lines only from the line `class Item {` through the last closing brace `}` — now look at _only_ that file. Looking at that file, where does `object2` in "myMethod" come from? No, don't look at Main.java ... looking _only_ at Item.java, where does `object2` come from? Nowhere. It's not declared anywhere in Item.java — it is not in the `Item` class, and "Item" does not know that Main.java exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *"... I'd like to change the value of an instance variable of an object inside a method, while that object hasn't called the method ..."*

Technically you can, if the object's variable is *[static](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)*.
Although, this does not appear to be logical for your current design.

> *"... I'd like to change object2.num inside the method myMethod, but that will give an error, as object2 is outside the scope of myMethod. ..."*

Correct, in Java, you won't be able to change an object's variable without the actual object.

> *"... The only solution I've come up with is to give object1 an additional instance variable, num2, which will act as object2.num. Outside of the method, I will then change object2.num to object1.num2. ..."*

You'll have to provide more details about the functional purpose of the task.

I recommend passing *object2* as a parameter to *myMethod*.
Additionally, I had to add a *return* here, since the method returns an *int*.

```java
public int myMethod(Item object2) {
    object2.num *= this.num;
    return this.num *= object2.num;
}
```

Or, you could just declare the method with a *void* return type.

```java
public void myMethod(Item object2) {
    object2.num *= this.num;
    this.num *= object2.num;
}
```

And then, supply *object2* as the argument.

```java
object1.myMethod(object2);
```

Output

```
16 8
```

Comment: Thank you, the purpose is to change instance variables of both objects based on the instance variables of the other object, and that within a method.

The int return type in the method declaration was supposed to be a void, sorry about that.

I didn't know you could supply an object as a parameter like that to a method, but that seems to be exactly what I was looking for! I'm assuming all the supplied object's instance variables that get changed within the method will also be changed within the main method? If so, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Beau, no problem, glad it helped.  _"... I didn't know you could supply an object as a parameter like that to a method ..."_, yes, since it is _of_ the enclosing class, somewhat confusing; logically it seems recursive.  It works.   _"... I'm assuming all the supplied object's instance variables that get changed within the method will also be changed within the main method? ..."_, yes, the object that is passed will be updated, thus the object within _main_ will have the corresponding values.